# Execute only some subset of integration tests with maven-failsafe-plugin

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

We have a set of integration tests, which all end with `IT`. Out of those, there is some specific subset, which we would like to execute separately. Let's say their names end with `SpecialIT`. So what we want to achieve is two configurations of the failsafe plugin:

- To execute all tests, ending with `IT`, but not with `SpecialIT` -> this is easy. Just normal inclusion and exclusion by those names.
- To execute all tests, ending with `SpecialIT`, but not all others `...IT`.

I thought it would be natural to create some dedicated profile and use a separate failsafe configuration with a negative lookbehind regex for that, so ended up with this configuration (had to use `&lt;` instead of `<`, as that one is not allowed there):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>%regex[.*(?&lt;!Special)IT.*]</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*SpecialIT.*</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I try to run this - I'm getting the following error:

```
Exclamation mark not expected in 'exclusion': %regex[.*(?<!Special)IT.*]
```

Reading the [documentation of the failsafe plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire-archives/surefire-3.0.0-M2/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) - I see this:

```
The syntax in parameter excludes and excludesFile should not use (!).
```

So the question is: is there any other way to achieve this, without, let's say, renaming all our integration tests into `...StandardIT` and `...SpecialIT`?

I was thinking in the direction of tags, test suit names or smth., but in our project we currently have a mix of JUnit5, JUnit4 and Spock (Groovy) tests, so it becomes not so straightforward.

P.S. If I just use this configuration - all `IT` tests are getting disabled and nothing is executed:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IT.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*SpecialIT.*</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: you do not need to configure `excludes`, you need to define two executions with mutually exclusive `includes`

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint! My problem was that I somehow was under an impression ([based on this](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)) that all `...IT` tests are always executed by default... But it is, of course, only until the `<includes>` is overwritten. So the "problem" is way simpler at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @andrey-b-panfilov, I realized that my problem was that I somehow was under an impression ([based on this](https://maven.apache.org/surefire-archives/surefire-3.0.0-M2/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)) that all `...IT` tests are always executed by default... But this is, of course, only until the `<includes>` is overwritten. So, the solution is eventually to just define the following two configurations:

- To execute all but `SpecialIT`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*SpecialIT.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

- To execute only `SpecialIT`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*SpecialIT.*</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```